# How to click a button that has a dynamic ID using selenium Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Im trying to press a button using selenium but the ID is generated every time I access the website. I've tried using the xpath and Css selectors that I get from Google Chrome but it appears to be using the ID so its unreliable. Heres the Html Code

```
<ul data-componentname="gender">

  <li id="4ed02d40-a727-4c69-9bb6-b39bcb752bfc" class="">
    <input type="button">
    <span>Male</span>
  </li>

  <li id="76e7055e-ac37-4d12-bec3-27f9ca3410c0" class="">
    <input type="button">
    <span>Female</span>
  </li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To Click on **Male**  or **Female** button induce `WebDriverWait` and `element_to_be_clickable` and following `xpath`

To click on Male:

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//ul[@data-componentname='gender']//li[./span[text()='Male']]/input[@type='button']"))).click()
```

To click on Female:

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//ul[@data-componentname='gender']//li[./span[text()='Female']]/input[@type='button']"))).click()
```

Note: You need to imports followings.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

---

**EDITED**

```
elementmale=WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//ul[@data-componentname='gender']//li[./span[text()='Male']]/input[@type='button']")))
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", elementmale)
```

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <input type="button"> is not clickable at point (684, 332). Other element would receive the click: <span>...</span>
  (Session info: chrome=76.0.3809.132)

Comment: Use JavaScript executor to click on this.check my updated code.